# Java RMI Interface RemoteException

Tags: java, rmi

I have the following setup using Java RMI:

```
private static ServerInterface serverInterface;
private static Registry serverRegistry;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        serverRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverAddress, serverTCPPort);
        String[] rpcList = serverRegistry.list();
        serverInterface = (ServerInterface) serverRegistry.lookup(rpcList[0]);
        debugPostIt("Server communication test succeeded.");
    } catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
        postIt("The specified server is not available!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    << Some code that calls methodA() and methodB(Object o)>>

}

private boolean methodA(){
    try{
        serverInterface.someMethodA();
    }catch(RemoteException e){
        System.out.println("Communication fail in A.")
    }
}

private boolean methodB(<<params>>){
    <<Create a new object based on B>>
    try{
        serverInterface.someMethodB(Object o);  // o is not Serializeable.
    }catch(RemoteException e){
        System.out.println("Communication fail in B.")
    }
}
```

Method A succeeds every time, however method B throws a RemoteException every time, even though the process running the interface was not stopped. It does not matter what order they are issued, A always succeeds, B always fails. When I change someMethodB to someMethodA within methodB, methodB no longer fails. I put simple checks on the remote object side to see if the method was even being accessed and it is not. Can someone tell me what might be occurring here?

**Edit:** Is there some requirement for passing objects in RMI methods, like the object must be serializeable or something similar to that?

Comment: So, what's happening in someMethodB?

Comment: `public boolean someMethodB(Article postedArticle) throws RemoteException {
  debugPostIt("Method B called!");
  
  return false;
 }`

I commented out everything in the method and just left it with this and it still fails. I never see the print at any point.

Comment: Sorry for that formatting...

Comment: You should have included the stack trace in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Hooray for answering my own questions!

My input argument to someMethodB() was a generic object that I had create that had not implemented Serializable. Adding that point to the class fixed the issue. Edited question to more accurately show the issue.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/implementing.html